# Запрет onclick при выделении текста

Tags: html

Как запретить срабатывание onclick при выделении текста в td ячейках

```html
<tr id="searchaname">
  <td width="250px" onclick="document.location = 'https://site.net';">
    <strong>1</strong>
  </td>

  <td onclick=" document.location='https://site.net/';">
    <p>2</p>
  </td>

  <td width="50px ">
    <p>
      <a href="/docs/1.pdf " target="_blank ">
        <img src="/img/download.png " alt=" " width="25 " height="25 ">
      </a>
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: что именно привести в порядок?

Comment: где именно проблема с кодом?